# Avoid Vertical ScrollBar in IE

Tags: javascript, html

We have a complex web application with many pages. It has a general layout using tiles and the details page is overridden in every page.
The problem that are facing is some of the pages have vertical scrollbars.
We have tried to determine the actual height of the components and set it to avoid scrollbars. But, this doesn't work on every page.
Please suggest a generic approach to avoid vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using **`CSS`** itself.

Usually the following `CSS` is used to avoid vertical scroll

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Comment: But, this will hide the content. I need something fluid or liquid in nature

Comment: If your content is larger than the height of the viewport and you don't want to hide any content scrollbars are your only option.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done in css using

```
html { overflow:auto; }
```

or

`html, body {
height: 100%;
}`

Comment: But, auto will display scrollbars. I somehow need to fit the content into the Viewport of the browser